# Upload a file to S3 using Chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, chef-infra, cookbook

I am automating installation of a distributed software using Chef. It has multiple nodes and on the master node, it creates an encryption key in a file. That file should be present on all the slave nodes. I was planning to publish this file to S3 from master node and download it on slave nodes. I know we can use s3_file cookbook to download file from s3. I don't know how to upload a file to s3 in Chef. So, looking for suggestion how can I upload to S3 or what is other workaround if s3 uploading is not available. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS CLI to upload a file to s3. If it is windows then use PowerShell to upload a file otherwise use a terminal script to do so. First, you need to install AWS CLI and then use AWS s3 cp command to upload a local file to AWS.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing specific in Chef for this, and I would highly recommend not handling this in Chef as then you have to deal with all kinds of race conditions when multiple nodes are booting simultaneously :) Probably just create and upload the key manually to your secrets management system (S3 buckets with ACLs are a simple option, but there is also SSM Parameter Store, or the newer AWS Secrets Manager), and then just deal with the download end from Chef.